# How can I determine a NuGet package source repository URL from the API or client SDK?

Tags: .net, api, sdk, nuget

(*Ed. Note:* This is not related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435407/find-nuget-package-source-repository), which asks about a different kind of source repository. It *may* be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450725/how-to-display-source-repository-of-a-nuget-package), but I am trying to differentiate.)

### Background/ Challenge

I am attempting to use the NuGet client SDK to programmatically work my way back from a package found on a machine to its source repository.

I am using the NuGet Client SDK, and I am able to pull package metadata. However, the source repository URL does not seem to be present in the metadata (only a project URL is present, and that is for a different URL).

Is there a way to get to this information without downloading a parsing the nuspec for the latest version, as indicated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450725/how-to-display-source-repository-of-a-nuget-package)?

[image: The NUnit project package on NuGet, with a link that says "Source repository" and a git icon highlighted.]

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the package on the machine there's no need to re-download it - you can find the package in your global cache (`C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages`) and parse the value out of the nuspec from there

Comment: Thanks, but in this specific situation that's not what I'm looking to do. I'm curious whether the information is available from an API call or via the client SDK without accessing a nuspec file, or whether I do have to get to the file itself (via either the file on disk or via the API call.)